# Недавно стало выдавать такую ошибку при установки библиотеки discord

Tags: python, pip, discord, discord.py

```
pip install discord 
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpap96lp7a'
         cwd: C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wefp14q9\aiohttp
    Complete output (24 lines):
    Error in sitecustomize; set PYTHONVERBOSE for traceback:
    SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xcc in position 0: invalid continuation byte (sitecustomize.py, line 21)
    running dist_info
    creating C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info
    writing C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing requirements to C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest template 'MANIFEST.in'
    warning: no files found matching 'aiohttp' anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyc' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.pyd' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.so' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.lib' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.dll' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.a' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files matching '*.obj' found anywhere in distribution
    warning: no previously-included files found matching 'aiohttp\*.html'
    no previously-included directories found matching 'docs\_build'
    writing manifest file 'C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    creating 'C:\Users\Максим\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-modern-metadata-xegscu_m\aiohttp.dist-info'
    error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\program files\python39\python.exe' 'c:\program files\python39\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pep517\_in_process.py' prepare_metadata_for_build_wheel 'C:\Users\2BA0~1\AppData\Local\Temp\tmpap96lp7a' Check the logs for full command output.
```

[image: Скрин ошибки]

Comment: Попробуйте, `pip install discord.py`

Comment: точно так же, ничего не меняется

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что имя пользователя написано кириллическими символами (Максим). Попробуйте обновить pip: `pip install --upgrade pip`, затем установить `discord.py`, если не получится, то установите вручную с [официального репозитория](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py)